# How to write SQL select with two grouped by groups and also include missing months for dates

Tags: sql, select, group-by

I have a table of Cars which basically includes a list of all sales. The table is as follows:

```
carType, soldDate, price
```

I would like to generate a result that shows the totals each month, including months with no entries (no sales), grouped by month and year of course, but also by `carType`. I have the following SQL query but I can't seem to figure out how to include all the missing months:

```
 SELECT 
        carType, YEAR(date) AS year, MONTH(date) as month,  SUM(amount)
    FROM
        cars
    GROUP BY 
        YEAR(date), MONTH(date), carType
    ORDER by    
        carType, year, month
```

I would also like to run the query with no set Start and End Date as well as a specified Start and Date (as in two different queries). Any assistance on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please tag which DBMS you are using

Comment: Missing dates are a real pain in SQL statements, if the data isn't there, it just isn't there, so you've got two options on that front, one do it in the code that receives the result set or have a prepopulated table with the minimum time increment you need for your report, and an additional column in the data table that has the minimum time increment format then you can left join those tables starting with the date table.  The easiest is just to do it in code downstream.  But if you have to do this a lot then the prepopulated table can makes sense as it can be reused.

Comment: @JeffRichards That's what I was afraid of :(

Comment: @Prisoner I'm trying to be DMBS agnostic

Comment: You will need a calendar table with all dates if you want to be database independent. The solution to dynamically generate values "on-the-fly" varies greatly from very easy (Postgres) to a bit cumbersome (Oracle, SQL Server) to very complicated (MySQL). But the query you have shown is already **not** DBMS agnostic.

Comment: Please tag properly.  Which dbms are you using?  People are trying to help you.  It's wasting everybody's time if we post solution to the wrong dbms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. As per JeffRichards comments about the question, if the data isn't there, it just isn't there. You can try to pre-populate it in another temporary table (which can be very complex) along with a number of other possible options but the best solution as Jeff stated is really to code it in another layer. That's what I did and the code was much fairly manageable.

If you're doing it in Java then you can create a list of the months and years you need with the following code:

```
// You could also .map() it to YearMonth instead of LocalDate's
// The plusMonths(1) is import so that it includes the last month
List<LocalDate> allMonths = Stream.iterate(startDate, date -> date.plusMonths(1))
        .limit(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(startDate, endDate.plusMonths(1)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then you go through the SQL generate list and add in any missing months:

```
allMonths.stream()
    .forEach(date ->
    {
        totalCarList.stream()
            .filter(car -> isSameMonthAndYear(car.getTotal().getDate, date))
            .findAny()
            .orElseGet(() ->
            {
                totalCarList.add(new Total(date, 0.00))
            });
    });
```

Finally you just re-sort the list by date:

```
totalCarList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Total::getDate));
```

Of course there are different ways but it's a lot less complicated then trying to push it into the SQL layer which is meant for working with existing data rather than trying to shove data in where it didn't exist before...

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have a table with the periods you want to show, with all years and months.

Then, make an outer join with the results of your query.